# How to insert special characters like &, () and others in Sparql using python?

Tags: python, graph, sparql, blazegraph

I am using this query to insert data:

```
prefix : <http://www.google.com/abc#>

INSERT DATA
{
     
:some&Data a :ABC .
}
```

But it is failing because of the `&`. How can I insert the data into Blazegraph db with special characters?
The same query like ```

````
prefix : <http://www.google.com/abc#>

INSERT DATA
{
     
:someData a :ABC .
}
``` passes without errors. I am using python to insert the data, but even in Blazegraph it fails.```

          ERROR: SPARQL-UPDATE: updateStr=prefix : 


INSERT DATA
{
     
:some&Data a :ABC .
}
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.openrdf.query.MalformedQueryException: Lexical error at line 7, column 7.  Encountered: "D" (68), after : "&"
````

Comment: Have you tried encoding the special characters?
E.g. using `u0026` instead of `&`, like this:
`<http://www.google.com/abc#some\u0026Data>`

Comment: reserved character escape sequences in local names consist of a \ followed by one of `~.-!$&'()*+,;=/?#@%_`  and represent the character to the right of the \, see the IRI reference in the specs:  https://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/#sec-iri-references